# persist file reference with html5

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am trying to play media files from local file system. The user now selects a file through 'input' and plays it. I wish to persist that file reference ,so that when the user visits next time , i should be able to tell him/her how many times he/she played it before when etc.,

I should either download the file reference from the server or store it locally .. any ideas how to perform this ?

Comment: I currently solving this temporarily, by asking the user to select the files everytime he/she opens the website. save the data in db , using the size in bytes as the unique id.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the information of the audio or video into client's side using `IndexedDB` or `localStorage`. Local Storage is easier to use IMO:

```
var obj = {
        "timestamp": new Date(),
        "title": "Blah Blah",
        "Performer": "Lady Blahblah"
    };

localStorage["previous"] = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

But notice that you won't be able to get the file's full path, and this prevent you from playing the same file next time. One possible solution is to store the file in `Base-64`, and directly put it into `<video>` or `<audio>`, which I am using this method to store file in the Google Chrome extension I made.

Comment: this will duplicate the whole data right ? ... I am currently considering to allow user to play whole set of songs .. :( 
if only i can store the file path it would have been awesome

Comment: @Skeptor - You can not know the full path because of security reason. Actually, storing all the songs in the database (WebSQL) is not a bad idea, since it is what it intended for.

Comment: so any idea how much it gets compressed (if any)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that you need to store the file itself? From what I read it sounded like you just want to be able to keep a tally of the times its been played. This could be accomplished by just hashing the file and then keeping your tally associated with the hash of the file rather than the file itself in something like localstorage.

Brief example using a javascript md5 implementation by someone i found on google included in the comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/b3b2V/2/

Comment: I might have 1000s files , hashing is difficult :( . I found a temporary  solution, added in comments of the question. Please comment on it

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to store the user.recent_files (just the names) in the database, and do some aggregate calculation to show him how many times he views it before.

What you can't do is to allow him to click on a link of a previously read file to read it again, well with HTML5 only I mean.

Rgds.